# Permissions issues while working with apache2 on mac

Tags: macos, permissions, apache-http-server

I am trying to create a local website on my Mac. I found that the default folder is /Library/WebServer/Documents/; so anything which I will paste here should be *published*.  However, when I start copying my web files and folders in this file, i need to periodically use chmod. This makes me feel that I am doing something wrong.

Here is my question: if I frequently need chmod or sudo to do anything in these folders, does it mean that I should have pointed Apache to some other location on my drive where I have more 'natural' access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working right. Under standard Unix filesystem permissions rules, files don't automatically adopt the settings of the folder they're copied into; I believe they are typically owned by the account doing the copying, with the permissions set to that user's `umask`.

To make sure that Apache doesn't serve up sensitive system files, Apache's `httpd` process runs as a special user account, `_www`. So when you copy files into `/Library/WebServer/Documents/`, you need to make sure they are either owned by, or at least readable by, `_www`.